# How to set intersection point of x and y axis

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am using d3.js for scatter plot,I want to plot x and y axis such that they intersect at point(100,75).how to do this?
I am using

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (padding+223) + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);

//Create Y2 axis
 svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + (padding+200) + ",0)")
   .call(yAxis2);
```

But this will not change according to the scale,and I have used variable for scale.
Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to offset the axes by the respective amount, which you can determine using the scales of the axes, i.e.

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + yScale(75) + ")")
  .call(xAxis2);
```

and similarly for the y axis. You may have to tweak the offset slightly to account for other offsets, labels etc.

Comment: Thanks its working now.Is there any solution to make Scatter plot workable in IE8.I have tried aight.js but  its thowing exception that 'Browser does not support this namespace'.Can you please help me

Comment: IE8 doesn't really work well with D3. [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) might be a better choice.